# Magento CE 1.7.0.2 Voucher with a $

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, coupon

we have in our shop an Voucher with a $. In the old CE it works but now in the 1.7.0.2 the voucher code doesn't work.
The big problem is, thousand of this vouchers are at our customers and ready to send.
What can I do, that Magento accept the Code?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tested on [ce-1.7.0.2](/questions/tagged/ce-1.7.0.2) and on [ce-1.8.1.0](/questions/tagged/ce-1.8.1.0) with the coupon codes `$aa` and `$aa$aaa$`. In both cases everything works perfectly.
Make sure your discount rules are not expired. Or maybe you have an extension interfering with the coupons